# Python 2.7, If statements being ignored and not being set/changed

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, python-2.7, function

My current if statements aren't working as I want them to, they should be changing a variable at certain times but the variable doesn't seem to change...

```
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep, strftime

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 10)
    s.run()

clearscreen = "false"

def clear():
    global clearscreen
    currenttime = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print currenttime


## When currenttime is in range, it should change clearscreen from false to true, but it doesn't
    if currenttime > "00:45:00" and currenttime < "00:46:00":
        print "Time Range 1 Working"
        if clearscreen == "false":
            print "Clear screen is set to false"
            clearscreen == "true"

## Same here, when currenttime is in range it should change clearscreen from true to false.
    if currenttime > "00:46:00" and currenttime < "00:47:00":
        print "Time Range 2 Working"
        if clearscreen == "true":
            print "clearscreen is set to true"
            clearscreen == "false"
            print "Cleared Screen"

getData()

run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 10, clear)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, also no need to mention about using UTC times.

Thanks
- Hyflex

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `"true"` and `"false"` instead of `True` and `False`?

Answer (score 6):

`clearscreen == "true"` with two `=`s doesn't change the value of `clearscreen`.  You need to write `clearscreen = "true"` (and later `clearscreen = "false"`) inside the `if` blocks (i.e., not on the `if` lines themselves) instead.

Comment: Ahh, such a small mistake. What does == change it to and how come I don't get a syntax error?

Comment: @Hyflex: `==` is a comparison operator that returns `True` if its operands are equal and `False` otherwise.  `=` is for variable assignment.